# How can I automate an install with numerical options?

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

For instance, if I was installing a package with apt-get, I would do:

`sudo apt-get install -y PACKAGE_NAME`

but in this case, my options when I manually install will be '1', '1' and '2' respectively. Can I compose a command with pipes to pass the input automatically?

Comment: Have you tried `echo -e "1\n1\n2" | sudo apt-get install PACKAGE_NAME`?

Comment: You should use puppet, chef, or ansible. What package are you trying to install?

Comment: I should clarify that I'm not actually trying to install a package with apt-get, but run a Python installer for a plugin that requires user input for some default options. I am using Chef to configure the rest of the installation, actually. I was just stuck on this particular step. I tried a variation on @KamilMaciorowski's answer of writing the answers to a dummy text file (one per line), and cat-ing that as input to ./setup.py which at least seems to finish without error - I'm assuming it's being read serially but can't verify for sure.